# Constructor list/array type parameters in the XML configuration

Tags: autofac, autofac-configuration

How can I pass an array/list parameter to the class constructor using the XML configuration?

If I want to pass a scalar value I use following configuration:

```
<components name="0">
        <type>XXX, XXX</type>
        <services name="0" type="XXX, XXX" key="YYY"/>
        <injectProperties>true</injectProperties>
        <instanceScope>single-instance</instanceScope>
        <parameters>
            <param1name>param1value</param1name>
            <param2name>param2value</param2name>
        </parameters>
</components>
```

The constructor of my class expects a parameter of the IEnumerable type .

Best regards,
arnam

Answer (score 1):

Short version: That's not currently supported. [Related issue here.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/issues/8)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with a JSON config but parameters arn't passed to the constructor. My config looks like that:

```
     "parameters":{
        "constructorParamName":["stringValue1", "stringValue2"]
     }
```

and the constructor is:

```
public MyClassConstructor(IList<string> constructorParamName = null)
```

Unfortunately "constructorParamName" value is always null.

**Update:**

I figured out that problem is caused by IContainer.ResolveNamed method. This method passes properties from a config file but doesn't passes constructor parameters.